# OBDKey Bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth

I want to connect my Motorola droid to `OBDKey` by Bluetooth. I use `BluetoothChat` as an example to connect to Bluetooth, with KWP as protocol

Then I write byte[] command

```
 command[0]=rawToByte(0x02);
 command[1]=rawToByte(0x85);
 command[2]=rawToByte(0x05);
 command[3]=rawToByte(0xc7);
 command[4]=rawToByte(0x33);
 command[5]=rawToByte(0xf1);
 command[6]=rawToByte(0x00);
 command[7]=rawToByte(0x00);
 command[8]=rawToByte(0x00);
 command[9]=rawToByte(0x00);
 command[10]=rawToByte(0x00);
 command[11]=rawToByte(0x00);
 command[12]=rawToByte(0x00);
 command[13]=rawToByte(0x00);
 command[14]=rawToByte(0x76);
```

where function "rawToByte" is:

```
public static byte rawToByte(int b) {
    return (byte) (0xff & b);
}
```

In the result OBDKey sent to device byte 0x02 This value is the first command, so it copy value. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The OBDKey is an ELM327 based bluetooth OBD adapter. It's just like the DealExtreme and scantool.net bluetooth adapters as far as features and method of use. I'm quite familiar with the latter two.

Here's how to send a string to the device, assuming you already opened the socket and stream, and the output socket is named mBTOutputStream

```
/**
 * Send the exact string provided. 
 * We don't append a CRLF or anything like that - we just send the exact string to the device as-is. 
 * @param sendThis - exact string to send to the device. 
 * @return - returns true unless a problem occurs, in which case we return false;
 */
public boolean sendRaw(String sendThis) {

        // Ya can't send data if we're not connected!
        if (isConnected() != true)
                return false;

        byte bsendThis[] = sendThis.getBytes();

        try {mBTOutputStream.write(bsendThis);} catch (Exception e) {
                ioErrorOccurredDuringOutput();
                return false;
        }

        ioResetOutputErrorCount();
        return true;
}
```

Also remember to also read from the device, otherwise the input buffer will become full and start blocking I/O.

Comment: Thanks for response, but what is the string "sendThis"?

Comment: You would use the method like this: `sendRaw("ATI" + "\n");` So when you execute the method it sends the string "sendThis".

Comment: Why I must send to device String when it understand only array of bytes(commands)?

What does function ioResetOutputErrorCount() do?

Comment: the ioError/ioReset methods are used to keep track of IO Errors in my app. I use it as an extra safety measure to know the integrity of the connection. You may remove them before using the method. As for the reason for using a String, it will make your life much better to work with Strings when communicating with this device and let the `sendRaw()` method convert the string to a byte array at the last minute - so you don't have to. Have you obtained the datasheet for the device yet so you know what commands to send it?

Comment: In fact, I already wrote an end to end application for the ELM327 Bluetooth devices. It's on the market as VoyagerConnect. I may be releasing parts of the source code in the future.

Comment: The sending commands depends on protocols(KWP,PWM,VPW and ISO ) . You can see more detail information there http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OBD-II_PIDs and in the source open  project OBDGauge

Are you sure that OBDKey bluetooth is an ELM327?
I read that they are different interfaces

Comment: The main problems that I write data to device, but it response the same first byte which I sent

Why do I give such response?

Comment: I guess that's the beauty of ELM327 - it hides all the complex logic to the point where people don't even know its an ELM327. You're missing a few key points that are making things difficult for yourself. 1. Yes it is an ELM327 chip. The ELM echo's back your commands along with the response, that is why you are seeing your request echo'd back to you. 2. You have to send the bytes to the device as a string not as binary. In other words, to read the DTCs you have to send the string "03\n" to the device. When that is translated to a `byte[]` it will become 0x30 0x33 0x10... do you understand?

Comment: Thanks now it is more clear. But what does "03\n" mean? How I will know what kind of String I must send?

Comment: "03\n" is a basic Java string. the \n is an escape character which translates to a single byte called a "line feed". A Line feed is equivalent to hitting the enter key on the keyboard. Every command you send to the ELM has to be terminated with \n. You will also notice that these characters (0x10 for \n and 0x13 for \r) in the ELM response. They are sent together, and separate the echo back, and the response from the ECU.

Comment: I done some test with My OBDKey
 At first I send the String "03\n" This is a list of conversation between my device(me)  and OBDkey using my program

me:03
OBDKey:0
OBDKey:3

I think this is wrong response.
So then I decided to connect to OBDKey using your program.
Result is
 Connected to OBDKey ,but then 
      -Initializing the ELM chip
      -INIT:ATZ=Fail...
      -sending init commands took 4 extra tries
      -Result from sendInitCommmands():false

Comment: How I understand , they were connected but it didn't send commands
So my application do the same, I need to send data succesful How can I do this?

Comment: Why do you think that is the wrong response? When you send 03, you will get a 0, a 3, a CR/LF, then the response to that command. I'm starting to wonder if you are understanding anything that I am telling you? You must read the elm327 data sheet like I told you. It won't make sense until you read it.

Comment: And how I must read the elm327 data sheet?

protected void startDevice() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
  sock = this.dev.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
        sock.connect();
        in = sock.getInputStream();
        out = sock.getOutputStream();
        while (!stop) {
         ObdCommand echoOff = new ObdCommand("ate0", "echo off", "string", "string");
         String result = runCommand(echoOff).replace(" ","");
         if (result != null && result.contains("OK")) {
          break;
         }
         Thread.sleep(1500);
        }
 }

Comment: This was example from obd-reader google.code Are you using it on your nice program how a base example? Can you give me example how I must read the elm327 data sheet? 

I'd appreciate that

Comment: The elm327 datasheet is actually a PDF document :) 
http://www.elmelectronics.com/DSheets/ELM327DS.pdf

Comment: Thanks it's great! I am trying to test my aplication, but the OBDKey didn't response to me

At first I send command : atsp0 - automatically find needed protocol
then I send : ate0 

in the result I want to give information about speed

Comment: public class SpeedObdCommand extends IntObdCommand {

 public SpeedObdCommand() {
  super("010D",ObdConfig.SPEED,"km/h","mph");
 }
 public SpeedObdCommand(SpeedObdCommand other) {
  super(other);
 }
 @Override
 public int getImperialInt() {
  if (intValue <= 0) {
   return 0;
  }
  return (int)(intValue * .625);
 }
}

Comment: The idea here is to ask a single question and answers and choose one. It's time to accept an answer. If you want more advice, we should take this offline, you can email  me at my gmail account Linuxbrad.

Answer (score 1):

OBDKey will actually encapsulate the KWP2000 frame for you (in the default ASCII mode).

All you need to do is tell the OBDKey unit to use the KWP2000 protocol with ATSP5\r, then after initialisation, send your request as "mode pid", e.g. 010C to get engine RPM.

Looking at your data, it is hard to work out what you are trying to do. The data you specified was: `02,85,05,C7,33,F1,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,76`

Usually the first byte is the header plus length, then target address byte, source address byte, data then checksum, e.g. `C2,33,F1,01,00,E7`. To send this example via OBDKey send `ATSP5\r` then `0100\r` and OBDKey will take car of the vehicle diagnostic protocol framing.